# How do I fix the hibernate validator problem with spring boot and ejb intergration

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, ejb, hibernate-validator

I am using some of the jars that have ejb services for a spring based rest interface I am trying to build. I am using spring boot for the project. I added the required dependencies, but the application is having issues with hibernate validator. Can someone please look at it and let me know what could be wrong with it? Please find the stack trace below:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.mrs.MrsApplication.main(MrsApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:33) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:296) ~[validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory.getObject(MessageInterpolatorFactory.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration.defaultValidator(ValidationAutoConfiguration.java:57) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Please find the dependencies from the pom.xml below:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Please find the mvn dependency tree below:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ mrs ---
[INFO] com.mrs:mrs:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to add `spring-boot-starter-validation` to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is for a `spring-boot-starter-web` adds a dependency to `hibernate-validator`, however spring needs to be added a `default validator` of hibernate as dependency.

Then you should exclude and add that dependency with latest version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. I tried changing the pom.xml, as per your suggestion. I am still seeing the same issue.

Comment: OK then remove the dependency added `hibernate-validator`

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. I tried both the approaches. It did not work. It looks like org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile has the hibernate component too. Do you know, by any chance, know how that can be excluded? I updated the pom.xml and the dependency section

Comment: Okay then excludes both dependencies and add the `hibernate-validator` again, please let me know if it works..